# Is It Proper Ruby Style to Extend Built-in Classes?

Tags: ruby

I realize this question may be too philosophical for StackOverflow, but I'm wondering if baseclassing built-in classes to extend their functionality is considered "good" Ruby style.

E.g.

```
class Grades < Array
  def sum
    sum = 0
    self.each do |num|
      sum += num
    end
    return sum
  end
  def avg
    self.sum/self.length
  end
end
```

Now Grades objects look like arrays when built, but have the additional sum and avg functions that I want access to. Would it be "better" style not to baseclass Array, but to add this functionality to a generic object?

Comment: for subjective / style questions, [programmers.se] might be a better place

Comment: I think it would be better in this case to just monkey patch `Array` itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

In general, everyone "monkey patches" everything in Ruby freely, from classes you wrote, to classes someone more important than you wrote, to library classes.

However, the general computing style guideline is if your class does everything, it does nothing. Your example accesses `each()` and `length()` efficiently, *but* your new `Grades` class now exposes *every* `Array` method, including ones you might not want called ~ and including ones that some cretin might someday go and monkey-patch! So if your `Grades` class were very public (used by your entire program), you might want to consider delegation.

Another guideline—that applies more in some languages than others—is you should never inherit unless you then override a method, to achieve polymorphism. Yet another rule which the entire Ruby community, including me, enjoys breaking freely.

Comment: inb4 someone points out the above example is not strictly "monkey patching". That would be adding .sum() and .avg() directly to Array. Same difference...

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful guidelines.

Comment: This is the "right way" to extend a class, but is not true monkey patching.  Monkey patching would be redefining the functionality of an existing method on the base class with out creating a new type.  Basically something like making Array.each() do something different.  What you are doing here is not polymorphism, it is inheritance and is the back bone of OOP.

Comment: I'd always thought monkey patching specifically referred to the `alias_method :meth_orig, :meth; def meth() foo; meth_orig end` pattern.  Good to know.

Comment: @numbers1311407 That’s a specific form of monkey-patching where you still want to be able to access the original functionality. That particular technique should also (thankfully) no longer be necessary with Ruby 2’s `prepend`.

Comment: Also, +1 on encapsulating the array within your class and then delegating or simply calling internally as needed, rather than exposing it completely.

Comment: Ben M. & Brett S. - yep there's plenty of ways to replace one patch of library code with another; all are monkeying with someone else's expectations (and adding more abilities to everything that ever sees or touches their objects, need them or not). U r correct that the true Monkey Patching, which Pythonistas eschew, extends a systemic class and overrides a method. Someone ought to find a cleaner way to get the same effect, such as adding a proc directly to an instantiated object's callable method list.

Answer (score 4):

For this case, I would say subclassing isn't really appropriate. A subclass should be a more specific version of its superclass—for example, `Fixnum` is a specific sort of `Integer` (it's a small integer stored in a particular way), which is a specific sort of `Numeric` (only some numbers are integers), which is a specific sort of `Object` (only objects that represent numbers are numerics). Your `Grades` class, on the other hand, is exactly equivalent to an `Array` except that it can calculate a couple more things about itself.

If `Grades` constrained something about the data it stored—for example, it only allowed you to insert numerics between 0.0 and 1.0 (or integers between 0 and 100, if you'd prefer)—it might make sense to subclass `Array`. On the other hand, it might also make sense to have `Grades` subclass `Object` directly, and keep the actual grades in an `Array` attribute.

Adding `sum` and `avg`, on the other hand, simply adds functionality that would be equally useful for other kinds of arrays, too. For such generic functionality, I would simply add those methods to `Array` so you don't have to worry about whether you've got a plain `Array` or a `Grades` in a particular place.

There are some gray areas here, of course—if you were proposing adding a `letter` method to convert the grades to an A through F grade letter, I wouldn't be so reluctant to subclass `Grades`. This is definitely a judgement call. But for this level of genericness, I really don't think subclassing is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, morals are freeer. Permissible is anything the programmer deems such. Actually, monkey patching existing classes is pretty much standard practice. Apart from what the other two answers said, let me bring your attention to the Ruby 2.0 `refine` feature, which allows you to monkey-patch within stricter boundaries, with less fear of undesirable interactions with other code.

But in your particular case, I think that your decision to create a separate class `Grades` might be a correct one. It's just a gut feeling, I'd have to be familiar with your codebase to say that for sure. It is less important, whether you make your `Grades` class a subclass of `Array`, or whether you just give it an attribute `@grade_array`, in which you will store actual grades and to which you will delegate the methods you want from `Array` class.